How can I get the app icon for any running app?
I am looking to create a custom taskbar in a WinUI3 app. I have code to get all open windows (based on this answer), but am now trying to get the icons associated with the process for each window. After much research, trial-and-error, and reading many other (ultimately failed) SO answers, I have a few different methods. Three of which are functional, but not comprehensive enough, and one doesn't work at all:
NOTE: For all of these methods, I get the executable of the app (sourcePath) with the following method:
private static string GetProcessExecutablePath(Process process) {
    try {
        StringBuilder buffer = new(1024);
        uint size = (uint) buffer.Capacity;
        IntPtr hProcess = process.Handle;

        if (QueryFullProcessImageName(hProcess, 0, buffer, ref size) != 0) {
            return buffer.ToString();
        }
    } catch (Win32Exception ex) {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Error accessing process handle for {process.ProcessName}: {ex.Message}");
    }

    return null;
}

1. [Functional] Extract the icon from the executable:
public static string ExtractIconFromFile(string sourcePath) {
    try {
        // using ensures that the Icon is disposed of
        using Icon icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(sourcePath);

        // using ensures that the Bitmap is disposed of
        using Bitmap bitmap = icon.ToBitmap();

        return bitmap.SaveToFile(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), ".TestTaskbar2", "AppIcons"), $"{desktopApp.AppName}_{Guid.NewGuid()}");
    } catch (Exception ex) when (ex is ArgumentNullException or IOException) {
        return null;
    }
}

This method fails when an app's icon is stored in another location, like the Start Menu shortcut file or a separate image file in the case of a UWP app. In that case, this function returns an image of the default executable icon. This method is also useless if the process that sourcePath comes from was running as administrator and the C# code isn't, as then the exe file (sourcePath) cannot be found in the first place.
2. [Functional] Extract the icon from the Start Menu shortcut by file path:
This code looks for a shortcut file in a start menu folder (I run it for both the user-specific and os-wide start menu folder) that points to the same executable, same directory, or a sub- or parent-directory of the app executable we are getting an icon for. It then gets the icon that the shortcut file uses.
private static List<string> FindShortcutIconsByPath(string directory, string sourceFile) {
    string appDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(sourceFile);

    List<string> icons = [];

    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.lnk", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) {
        WshShell shell = new();
        IWshShortcut shortcut = null;
        try {
            shortcut = (IWshShortcut) shell.CreateShortcut(file);
            string targetPath = shortcut.TargetPath;
            string targetDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(targetPath);

            // App location exists and target location exists and app does not reside in C:\Windows or C:\Windows\System32
            // (Many windows apps are housed in Windows and System32, and all of their icons will be found for...
            // ...each one of the apps, with no way to distinguish by path which is right)
            if (appDirectory is not null && targetDirectory is not null && !appDirectory.ToLower().Equals(@"c:\windows") && !appDirectory.ToLower().Equals(@"c:\windows\system32")) {
                // Target points to the exact folder the app is in,
                // or target points to a subfolder of app's location,
                // or app is in a subfolder of where target points
                if (targetDirectory.Equals(appDirectory, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                    || targetPath.StartsWith(appDirectory, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                    || appPath.StartsWith(targetDirectory, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
                    icons.Add(ExtractIconFromFile(shortcut.IconLocation ?? targetPath));
                }
            }
        } finally {
            // COM objects must be released to prevent memory leaks
            if (shortcut != null) {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(shortcut);
            }

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(shell);
        }
    }

    return icons;
}

Sometimes, the Start Menu shortcut will point to a different executable for the same app (like an updater, installer, or launcher for example), so this code tries to account for that by comparing folders and looking within subfolders. However, it is not perfect, and can still miss apps or find too many icons from other executables (I tried to account for that with the Windows and System32 folders, but I can't do it for everything). In those cases, there is no programmic way to determine which icon is the correct one.
3. [Functional] Extract the icon from the Start Menu shortcut by name:
This code is similar to the one above, but finds the start menu shortcuts by matching their names to the app.
private static List<string> FindShortcutIconsByName(string directory, string appName) {
    List<string> icons = [];

    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.lnk", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) {
        WshShell shell = new();
        IWshShortcut shortcut = null;
        try {
            if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file).ToLower().Replace("microsoft", "").Trim() == appName.ToLower().Replace("microsoft", "").Trim()) {
                shortcut = (IWshShortcut) shell.CreateShortcut(file);
                icons.Add(ExtractIconFromFile(shortcut.IconLocation ?? shortcut.TargetPath));
            }
        } finally {
            // COM objects must be released to prevent memory leaks
            if (shortcut != null) {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(shortcut);
            }

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(shell);
        }
    }

    return icons;
}

As you might imagine, this method often fails to find a shortcut, but is intended as a backup. The good news is that when it does find a shortcut, it is quite reliably the correct icon.
4. [Failed] - Get UWP app icons
I attempted to use the code in this answer to get icons for UWP apps, but it simply returns null for every single process and I'm not sure why.
Here is my slightly modified implementation of the code in that answer: https://pastebin.com/rAuFgXge. It mostly has to do with VS cleaning up a lot of formatting and style preferences, and I changed the Show method to be a method of AppxPackage rather than a standalone function. It also uses Debug.WriteLine rather than Console.Writeline as I want to see the output in the VS debugger.
EDIT: Here is how I called the code for testing:
foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses()) {
    AppxPackage package = AppxPackage.FromProcess(p);
    if (package != null) {
        package.Show();
        Debug.WriteLine("\n\n");
    } else {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Could not find package for {p.ProcessName}");
    }
}

The Problem
Using these 3 methods in conjunction, I can sometimes find 3 good icons (in which case I pick the highest resolution one), sometimes get a good icon out of one of them, sometimes get no good icons at all (I'll get the default windows executable icon, or default to a placeholder), or sometimes get a dozen icons, only one of which is right.
For some apps, it's better to take the executable over the Start Menu shortcut icons, for others it's better to take the shortcut icons over the executable, and I'm not sure how to programmically decide which is better. For now my plan is to allow the user to choose between possible app icons, or upload their own, but this is not ideal.
The biggest problem lies in UWP apps. Because of their complicated and inconsistent app structure, none of these methods work on them. The folders in which icons are often stored are inconsistently named and placed at best, and the plethora of icons inside makes it impossible to reliably select one.
So, as a whole...
How can I get an an app icon for UWP apps (and reliably get an app icon for other apps)

For UWP, there are many icon files, and you need to traverse the entire folder where UWP is located. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/iconography/app-icon-construction

The code in my answer doesn't return null for every package and should get you logo information. Please provide a fully reproducing code.

@JunjieZhu-MSFT The code from the answer linked (and in the pastebin) should do that.

@SimonMourier I edited the question to include how I tested it (it also didn't work in my actual implementation, but that is the MRE and checks all processes rather than the select windows in my final implementation). I will try using your code verbatim though, although I made no functional changes other than Console --> Debug so I can see the output.

I added test code with more debug prints, as well as the full output from the debug window, to the following pastebin: https://pastebin.com/hFdpZzXt. The "exception thrown" lines are very common with DLL imports, and none of those were thrown as exceptions in my actual code. Usually they are not a concern, and haven't been a problem with any of my functioning code.

My code is a test code that look for AppX packages in every process running. But most processes running on Windows are not AppX applications (=> don't have packages) so exceptions are fully expected, it's by design. Have you tried to run the latest notepad (https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9msmlrh6lzf3?hl=en-US&gl=US) or calculator (https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9wzdncrfhvn5?hl=en-US&gl=US) and run the code. It should work for both of these and return their logo. For non AppX app, you must use a different code.

@SimonMourier I understand that, but I should have some processes that are UWP apps. I even tried opening apps like netflix and sticky notes which have the UWP file structure. However, I’ll try out notepad and calculator tomorrow morning when I get to my computer.
